# What does "use either result" mean in the Goliath's "Powerful Athlete" feature?

Tags: dnd-4e, racial-traits, goliath

My friends and I are playing D&D 4e now, and for the first time someone decided to roll a Goliath character. The "Powerful Athlete" racial feature states that

> When you make an Athletics check to jump or climb, roll twice and use either result

But since we all are not native English speakers, we got confused about what "either" means in that context. Should I use both rolls, or just pick one that is higher?

Comment: Just as a note, if you ever have a question about the English language again, the folks over at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) are great.

Comment: Seems like a precursor to Advantage!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### You choose the one you want

This simply means you roll two times and then choose the one you prefer – which is probably the higher result. You are not required to use the second result (e.g. if the first result was better).

For example, if you roll a "14" and a "7", you can choose to use the result of "14", or you can choose to use the result of "7" instead. (The result you want is probably "14".)